# Python Fastapi with existing database?

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, rest

I'm learning to use fastapi with postgresql. I have a huge database from other project and its already complete as postgre database... so I try to add fastapi but don't know how can I do this... it seems that you must create all the db schemas with fastapi right from the start... I can't find any helpfull example so I hope you can guide me. Thank you for your time and excuse my english

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/) to create the SQLalchemy models from your existing database.